# How to find the first NALunit of one complete video frame in raw HEVC/H.265 stream?

Tags: hevc, h.265

In a raw HEVC/H265 elementary stream, how to find the first NALunit of one video frame? Access unit delimiter/access_unit_delimiter_rbsp() seems to be a good choice, but it is optional in the video stream.

Comment: Already found the answer in the HEVC spec 7.4.2.4.5 Order of VCL NAL units and association to coded pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read the hevc specification . I never did but I can help a little by my experience in the HM codec.

in the beginning the current pos in bitstream is 0, the decoder extracts and discards all bytes ( `leading_zero_8bits` ) until he finds  0x00000001 or 0x000001 then he discard 3 or 4 bytes mentioned before ( `zero_byte` and `start_code_prefix_one_3bytes` ), then he reads all 3 bytes ( in loop ) until he finds 0x000003 or the end of the stream , this is the actual data . then if it’s not end of stream and not 0x00000001 or 0x00001 he will discard all bytes (`trailing_zero_8bits`) until he finds them , which means new NALu or end of stream. However, a frame could be represented with more then 1 NALu.

After that he convert the payload To RBSP by clearing `EmulationPreventionByte` and removing  `cabac_zero_word` before the decoding starts.